# How to find $\frac {dy}{dx}$ at the point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=\dfrac{3x^2}{1-4x}$

I am solving through u/v formula but its not working for me

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ for $x=1$.

Comment: Let $u=3x^{2} \implies u'= ?$ And let $v=1-4x \implies v'=?$ Then just use the quotient rule $\frac{vu'-uv'}{v^{2}}$. Althernatively, use the product rule by letting $u=3x^{2}$ and $v=(1-4x)^{-1}$.

Comment: Note that you can divide through first if you find it more convenient, to give $y=-\frac {3x}4-\frac 3{16}+\frac 3{16}\cdot \frac 1{1-4x}$ and then differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

By the quotient rule, this derivative is

$$
\frac{(3x^2)'(1-4x) - (3x^2)(1-4x)'}{(1-4x)^2} = \frac{12x^2 + 6x - 24x^2}{(1-4x)^2}\\
= \frac{-12x^2 + 6x}{(1-4x)^2}
$$

at $x=1$, you get $\dfrac{-12 + 6}{(-3)^2} = -\dfrac23$

Comment: This is actually incorrect... you have the quotient rule the wrong way around.

Comment: It's $u'v-uv'$ in the numerator, not $uv'-u'v$. In otter words, your answer is the negative of what it's supposed to be.

Comment: the answer is correct @JpMcCarthy

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra No it isn't: simple as. The answer should be $\displaystyle -\frac{2}{3}$. Last time I checked, $\frac23\neq -\frac23$...

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra You are the OP! You don't know the answer almost by definition.

Comment: :@ the answer is 2/3 is solve by putting the right way of u/v formula its right answer and i confirmed it through book @JpMcCarthy

Comment: sorry, just waking up. of course, @jp mcarthy is correct, and the sign should be switched. the answer is now edited to be correct.

Comment: The answer has been edited and is now correct... and my downvote has been removed. Tayab the book is wrong because the answer is $-\frac23$.

Comment: Hey Tayyab maybe the book has an error or a misprint or something but JPMcCarthy is definitely right (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+y%3D3x%5E2%2F+%281%E2%88%924x%29++at+x+%3D+1). You can also tell the derivative should be negative by graphing the function (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+y%3D3x%5E2%2F+%281%E2%88%924x%29+)

Comment: @JpMcCarthy your corrected my i checked three times and you were right

Comment: the answer was 2/3 @JpMcCarthy

Comment: ...and that answer was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go from first principles, let $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{3x^2}{1-4x}$ consider $(1,f(1))=(1,-1)$. Take a point along the curve $(1+h,f(1+h))$ and find the slope of this *secant* using the rise over the run to approximate:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&\approx \frac{\frac{3(1+h)^2}{1-4(1+h)}-(-1)}{h}
\\&=\frac{3(1+h)^2+1(1-4-4h)}{h(-3-4h)}
\\&=\frac{3+6h+3h^2-3-4h}{h(-4h-3)}
\\&=\frac{3h^2+2h}{h(-4h-3)}
\\&=\frac{h(3h+2)}{h(-4h-3)}
\\ &\underset{h\neq0}{=}\frac{3h+2}{-4h-3}
\end{align}$$

Now as $(1,f(1))$ and $(1+h,f(1+h))$ get closer and closer together so that $h\rightarrow 0$, this converges to $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{3h+2}{-4h-3}=\frac{3(0)+2}{-4(0)-3}=-\frac{2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(3x^2)\cdot(1-4x)-\frac{d}{dx}(1-4x)\cdot(3x^2)}{(1-4x)^2}$$

Now simplify and plug in $x=1$.